# Why its not possible to read varables from .env file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this configuration variables in my .env files

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://password@postgres:port/dbmt?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=10000
```

now with them i would like configure my database

```
development:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'].gsub('?', '_development?') %>
```

but when i tried:

```
rake db:migrate
```

i got this error:

Caused by:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

; _erbout.<<(( ENV['DATABASE_URL'].gsub('?', '_development?') ).to_s); _erbout.<< "\n\ntest:\n  url: ".freeze
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't ship with an out-of-the-box way to handle environment variables (not up to now as I'm aware of), but you can easily manage them with [bkeepers/dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem.

You can first add it to your Gemfile file (and specify any environment if necessary), then run bundle and that should make it work;

```
# Gemfile
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

then bundle;

```
$ bundle
```

and then run the rake `db:migrate` again.

Alternatively, if you don't want or can't add the above-mentioned gem you could pass the environment variable on the command itself;

```
$ DATABASE_URL=postgresql://password@postgres:port/dbmt?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=10000 rake db:migrate
```

but that might have more cons than pros.

Comment: i am getting the same error

Comment: try reloading your shell (`source ~/.bashrc`, `source ~/.zshrc` or simply opening a new terminal), do you have the same error? @tongson

Comment: yes i used your commands for terminal, i oppened other terminal as well, i am getting the same error

Comment: can you see any reference to dotenv in the Gemfile.lock file?

Comment: no at all, there is not there

Comment: so maybe the  `bundle` command errored, can you try running it once again?

Comment: i tried many times i am getting the same error

Comment: if you don't see the gem in the Gemfile.lock then you won't be able access environment variables with it, try the second example given, do you run into the same error?

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE_URL` needs to be defined in the environment that you were running `rake` from. It looks like if you're using `bash` (or similar) you want to `source myfile.env` first.

Since it doesn't currently exist, the `ENV[]` lookup fails, returning `nil`, which doesn't have a `gsub` method.

Comment: how can i solve that?

Comment: By sourcing the file first, like I noted.